How to give image file to gemini multimodal api in Firebase extension
I am currently working on a project of asking ai to tell me what is then name of the cartoon character inside an image. I chosen to use the Multimodal Tasks with the Gemini API extension in Firebase.
In configuration I chosen Vertex AI as provider, gemini-1.0-pro-vision as gemini model, "imagefile" as image field for gemini, with the prompt "Analysis the image from this file {{imagefile}} link and tell me the name of this character."
And I then uploaded the image to "storage" of Firebase and followed the following rulesenter image description here to get the string of image field.
Then back to the Firestore database, I created new document and inputted the string url to the field "imagefile", and gemini return the following output to me.
enter image description here
Can anyone help me with this? How to ask gemini to read an image as it is written in description that I can chat with gemini with images. Thanks.
I had tried changing the prompt like "What is this character?" without the image path, or "Analyse the image attached", but either it always return the same but wrong answer which show it does not even read the image or returned "sorry I cannot read the image url...".

Show the code or the REST API call you are making. Note: do not attach images of text to your question. Copy and paste the text messages into your question.
